# SSRS Report - Why does multi value parameter only return maximum value selected?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have an SSRS/Report Builder report that connects to a dataset in the PBI service. It has several parameters, and one of the parameters works fine when designed to select one value.  I change the parameter properties to allow multi-selecting. When I run the report I am able to select multiple values, but the report only brings back the maximum value selected in the dropdown. The list is alphabetical, so it returns the highest value selected in alphabetical order. I did add a filter so that it searches where the value is 'in' the parameter (vs '='), but that didn't make a difference.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?